# Finding a group that is not monomial

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

**Definition.** A group is called monomial if every representation of $G$ is induced from 1-dimensional representations of some subgroup of $G$.

**Question** Give an example of a group that is not monomial.

The only thing I can find is a corollary (of the F. Reproc. 
 Theorem) that says:

Suppose $H<G$, $H$ abelian and $[G:H]=n$. Then every irreducible representation of $G$ has dimension $\leq n$.

Therefore it seems that $G=D_3=S_3$ (sometimes called $D_6$) would work, but the corollary is not if and only if.

No full solutions please, and I am not familiar with modules.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the statement "if we have an abelian subgroup $H$ of $G$ it will induce from a $1$-dimensional representation". What is *it*? Certainly all *irreducible* representations of abelian groups are $1$-dimensional. While I've only worked with characters and not representations, I'd be willing to bet that almost all sufficiently large non-abelian groups are not monomial. What's stopping you from confirming that $S_3$ isn't monomial?

Comment: @pjs36 Usually for these types of questions there is a corollary or theorem etc which suggests how to prove that counterexample, ie by relaxing one of the conditions so that the result no longer holds. It is often good to understand the approach as to how you build counterexamples. What is stopping me from confirming that $S_3$ isnt monomial is that I am trying to find the easiest way of doing this.

Comment: Have you found *a* way of doing this? It is a terribly bad plan to look for *good ways* to do something before even having even a mediocre way of doing it...

Comment: Unfortunately $S_3$ is monomial (as are all supersolvable groups).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monomial groups are solvable hence every non-solvable groups are example. You can take $G=A_5$ for example.

Comment: Is there a simple reason why monomial groups are solvable? Should I have seen this? I do not have this as a theorem in my notes

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial_group , You can find the proof in Isaac's character theory book. I think it is one of the basic properties of these groups.